# What is the efficient way to remove subsets from a List[List[String]]?

Tags: scala

I have a ListBuffer of `List[String]`, `val tList = ListBuffer[TCount]` where `TCount` is `case class TCount(l: List[String], c: Long)`. I want to find those list `l` from `tList` which are not the subset of any other element of `tlist` and their `c` value is less than their superset `c` value. The following program works but I have to use two for loop that makes the code inefficient. Is there any better approach I can use to make the code efficient?

```
    val _arr = tList.toArray

    for (i <- 0 to (_arr.length - 1)) {
      val il = _arr(i).l.toSet
      val ic = _arr(i).c
      for (j <- 0 to (_arr.length - 1)) {
        val jl = _arr(j).toSet
        val jc = _arr(j).c
        if (i != j && il.subsetOf(jl) && ic >= jc) { 
          tList.-=(_arr(i))
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Here are a few hopefully inspiring links: [Set-trie](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01506780/document), [FP-growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning#FP-growth_algorithm).

Comment: You seemed to ask for a more efficient solution, but accepted a more concise one that used `combinations(2)` instead of two nested loops. You might want to clarify the question and state clearly that you want a more concise solution, not a more efficient one.

Comment: You are right, both taking almost the same time :(

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the set-trie comment:

```
import scala.collection.SortedMap

class SetTrie[A](val flag: Boolean, val children: SortedMap[A, SetTrie[A]])(implicit val ord: Ordering[A]) {
  def insert(xs: List[A]): SetTrie[A] = xs match {
    case Nil => new SetTrie(true, children)
    case a :: rest => {
      val current = children.getOrElse(a, new SetTrie[A](false, SortedMap.empty))
      val inserted = current.insert(rest)
      new SetTrie(flag, children + (a -> inserted))
    }
  }

  def containsSuperset(xs: List[A], strict: Boolean): Boolean = xs match {
    case Nil => !children.isEmpty || (!strict && flag)
    case a :: rest => {
      children.get(a).map(_.containsSuperset(rest, strict)).getOrElse(false) ||
        children.takeWhile(x => ord.lt(x._1, a)).exists(_._2.containsSuperset(xs, false))
    }
  }
}

def removeSubsets[A : Ordering](xss: List[List[A]]): List[List[A]] = {
  val sorted = xss.map(_.sorted)
  val setTrie = sorted.foldLeft(new SetTrie[A](false, SortedMap.empty)) { case (st, xs) => st.insert(xs) }
  sorted.filterNot(xs => setTrie.containsSuperset(xs, true))
}
```

Comment: Just re-read the relevant part of the paper: your code looks closer to the Set-Trie from the paper than what I wrote. My `isMaximal` is almost trivial, your `containsSuperset` looks rather complicated. On the other hand, my `insert` is rather complicated (with taking tails etc.), whereas your `insert` looks like a rather straightforward linear recursion. I guess it's a trade-off between the effort during creation and effort during search. Good job (+1).

Comment: Fun fact: my `toString` turned out to be source code compatible with your code xD (that's really absolutely accidental, I didn't see your posting when I wrote my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that relies on a data structure somewhat similar to Set-Trie, but which stores more subsets explicitly. It provides worse compression, but is faster during lookup:

```
def findMaximal(lists: List[List[String]]): List[List[String]] = {

  import collection.mutable.HashMap

  class Node(
    var isSubset: Boolean = false, 
    val children: HashMap[String, Node] = HashMap.empty
  ) {
    def insert(xs: List[String], isSubs: Boolean): Unit = if (xs.isEmpty) {
      isSubset |= isSubs
    } else {
      var isSubsSubs = false || isSubs
      for (h :: t <- xs.tails) {
        children.getOrElseUpdate(h, new Node()).insert(t, isSubsSubs)
        isSubsSubs = true
      }
    }
    def isMaximal(xs: List[String]): Boolean = xs match {
      case Nil => children.isEmpty && !isSubset
      case h :: t => children(h).isMaximal(t)
    }
    override def toString: String = {
      if (children.isEmpty) "#"
      else children.flatMap{ 
        case (k,v) => {
          if (v.children.isEmpty) List(k)
          else (k + ":") :: v.toString.split("\n").map("  " + _).toList
        }
      }.mkString("\n")
    }
  }

  val listsWithSorted = for (x <- lists) yield (x, x.sorted)
  val root = new Node()
  for ((x, s) <- listsWithSorted) root.insert(s, false)

  // println(root)

  for ((x, s) <- listsWithSorted; if root.isMaximal(s)) yield x
}
```

Note that I'm allowed to do any kind of mutable nonsense inside the body of the method, because the mutable trie data structure never escapes the scope of the method, and can therefore not be inadvertently shared with another thread.

Here is an example with sets of characters (converted to lists of strings):

```
println(findMaximal(List(
  "ab", "abc", "ac", "abd",
  "ade", "efd", "adf", "bafd",
  "abd", "fda", "dba", "dbe"
).map(_.toList.map(_.toString))))
```

The output is:

```
List(
  List(a, b, c), 
  List(a, d, e), 
  List(e, f, d), 
  List(b, a, f, d), 
  List(d, b, e)
)
```

so indeed, the non-maximal elements `ab`, `ac`, `abd`, `adf`, `fda` and `dba` are eliminated.

And here is what my not-quite-set-trie data structure looks like (child nodes are indented):

```
e:
  f
b:
  e
  d:
    e
    f
  c
  f
d:
  e:
    f
  f
a:
  e
  b:
    d:
      f
    c
    f
  d:
    e
    f
  c
  f
c
f
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can avoid the complexity, but, I guess I'd write like this:

```
val tList = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(3, 2, 1), List(9, 4, 7), List(3, 5, 6), List(1, 5, 6), List(6, 1, 5))

val tSet = tList.map(_.toSet)
def result = tSet.filterNot { sub => tSet.count(_.subsetOf(sub)) > 1 }
```

Comment: Got output `Set(9, 4, 7), Set(3, 5, 6)`, but it should be `Set(9, 4, 7), Set(3, 5, 6), Set(1, 2, 3), Set(1, 5, 6)`.

Comment: That's the same output as your code. The order does not count? [1, 2, 3] is not a subset of [3, 2, 1]? you should change for equals instead of subsetOf then.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

1. Create an `indexed Map` for identifying the original List elements
2. Turn Map of List-elements into `Map of Sets` (with index)
3. Generate `combinations` of the Map elements and use a custom filter to capture the elements that are `subset` of others
4. Remove those `subset` elements from the Map of Sets and retrieve remaining elements from the Map of Lists via the index

Sample code:

```
type TupIntSet = Tuple2[Int, Set[Int]]

def subsetFilter(ls: List[TupIntSet]): List[TupIntSet] = 
  if ( ls.size != 2 ) List.empty[TupIntSet] else
    if ( ls(0)._2 subsetOf ls(1)._2 ) List[TupIntSet]((ls(0)._1, ls(0)._2)) else
      if ( ls(1)._2 subsetOf ls(0)._2 ) List[TupIntSet]((ls(1)._1, ls(1)._2)) else
        List.empty[TupIntSet]

val tList = List(List(1,2), List(1,2,3), List(3,4,5), List(5,4,3), List(2,3,4), List(6,7))

val listMap = (Stream from 1).zip(tList).toMap
val setMap = listMap.map{ case (i, l) => (i, l.toSet) }

val tSubsets = setMap.toList.combinations(2).toSet.flatMap(subsetFilter)

val resultList = (setMap.toSet -- tSubsets).map(_._1).map(listMap.getOrElse(_, ""))
// resultList: scala.collection.immutable.Set[java.io.Serializable] =
//   Set(List(5, 4, 3), List(2, 3, 4), List(6, 7), List(1, 2, 3))
```